# How to model survival panel data in R?

Tags: r, survival

How do you model panel data in a survival model?

I am unsure how to model repeated cases (or `id`) in `coxph`, since the common form is:

`fit <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ x1, data=df)`

Here is a slice of the data:

```
> head(d)
  year month id demmonth demend      dev      gro
1 2002     7  1        1      0 8.308352 6.869293
2 2002     8  1        2      0 8.308352 6.869293
3 2002     9  1        3      0 8.308352 6.869293
4 2002    10  1        4      0 8.308352 6.869293
5 2002    11  1        5      0 8.308352 6.869293
6 2002    12  1        6      0 8.308352 6.869293
```

The `time` variable is demmonth.

The `event` variable is demend.

The predictors are `dev + gro`.

A common survival model would look like:

`fit <- coxph(Surv(demmonth, demend) ~ dev + gro, data=df)`

But, since my dataset is comprised of repeated observations of many different `id`s over time, how can I model panel data via survival?

Full data can be found here: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocketfish88/democ/master/MaedaCSV2.csv`

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: Please do not repost questions that have been closed as off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to add another time column. Each row should have initial and end time of each spell so that the end time of row `i` equals the start time of row `i+1`. Sort the data by id and time, and the model will do the rest. This way the model will understand that when `t0==0`, a new id has started.

Thus, your data should have the following structure:

```
  year month id demmonth t0  t2      dev      gro
1 2002  8     1    1      0   1      8.308352 6.869293
2 2002  9     1    2      1   2      8.308352 6.869293
3 2002  10    1    3      2   3      8.308352 6.869293
etc...
```

The model will be:

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(t0, t1, demend) ~ dev + gro, data=df)
```

See [*Using Time Dependent Covariates*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) for more detailed information.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and help!